# JSF annotations ignored when deploy other then to JBoss

Tags: jsf, jboss, application-server

My simple JSF app is running on JBoss 7 but when I deploy it to Jetty - JSF annotations are ignored, and I have to define ManagedBean in faces-config.xml to make it work because managedBean resolved to null when I submit the form. JBoss is not mentioned in pom.xml dependencies, so looks like JSF by default tied up with JBoss.

How to make project stop being close friends with JBoss?

Answer (score 2):

JSF 2.0 is part of the Java EE specification so it is definitely not bound to an application server in particular.
You should check out that the version of the Web container (Jetty) supports JSF 2.0 and that you have added all the required dependencies.
Hope it helps
Francesco

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, but I was tired to play with it and switched to another archetype. Thanx for answer..